# How to install Xibo Client on Raspberry Pi Model B?

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B and need to install the digital signage Xibo Client, the OS installed on the Raspberry Pi is Raspbian 7.

I followed this tutorial step by step three times but it gave the same error three times "make install failed"

http://rpiserver.breggen.nl/building_xibo.html

The Xibo site has a script to install on ubuntu (that uses the same kernel), I tried to use it but it failed.

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/174494959/xibo-1.6.0-ubuntu.all-pyclient.sh

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an english only site. Please [edit] your question title to be in english.

Comment: We can help you if you provide us more information... The output after running the script with the error message would be particularly useful.

Comment: I followed this instruction http://rpiserver.breggen.nl/building_xibo.html
when I run the command "útil / build-chromium.sh" he download some files and at the end of the script he error.